# Is it possible to get VS 2010 to build before running tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have a Class Library project in Visual Studio 2010 that I want to test. I have created a seperate Test project in the same solution to test it. The Test project references the Class Library project. I created some tests ran them and they failed which was expected. However when I fixed the Class Library and ran the tests again it still failed. This was because the Class Libary project had not been rebuilt.

Is there some way to get Visual Studio 2010 to automatically build the Test project and all its dependancies before running the tests?

EDIT:

Some things I have checked:

1. I've checked the reference is a project reference.
2. I've checked the Test project is last in the build order.

Still no joy. In case it makes any difference I am running the tests using the "Run All Tests in Solution (Ctrl+R, A)" button on the tool bar.

Comment: How did you add the reference to the production code? This works fine for me.

Comment: If you add the reference to your class library as project reference, the tests project should work without building the class library project before.

Comment: You sure? Normally this works. It has not even sth. to do with testing. It's just a usual project reference which normally leeds to all dependent projects being built in the right order.

Comment: I've checked the reference is a project reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Here is what I did to fix this:

1. Select the Test->Edit Test Settings->Local menu item.
2. In the resulting dialog select Deployment.
3. Check the 'Enable deployment' setting.
4. Apply and Close the dialog.

Comment: Glad, it works. But I am curious what does 'enable deployment' have to do with the build order.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your test project, select Project Build Order and set your class library project to build before your test project, this should works ;-)